# Get access token form google authentication

Tags: angularjs, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am using the following controller to import contacts from google account. I got the authorization code after login in gmail. But couldnt able to get the  accesstoken by posting the authorization code to the url 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'. I didnt get any response.

```
    angular.module('app',['ngRoute','angular-google-gapi'])
        .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider
                    .when('/log-in', {
                        template: '<button ng-click="logInCtrl.onLogInButtonClick()">Log In</button>',
                        controller: 'LogInController',
                        controllerAs: 'logInCtrl'
                    }).otherwise({
                        redirectTo:'/log-in'
                    });
        }])
        .controller('LogInController',function($scope,$http,GAuth,GApi){

            var self = this; 
            var client_id = clientid;
            var client_secret =clientsecretkey;
            var redirect_uri ='http://localhost/myapp/oauth2callback';
            var grant_type='authorization_code';
            var apiKey=  myapikey;
            var scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full';//to be able to reference to it in a callback, you could use $scope instead
             $scope.email = '';
             gapi.load('auth2', function() {//load in the auth2 api's, without it gapi.auth2 will be undefined
                gapi.auth2.init(
                        {
                            client_id: clientid
                        }
                );
                var GoogleAuth  = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();//get's a GoogleAuth instance with your client-id, needs to be called after gapi.auth2.init
                self.onLogInButtonClick=function(){//add a function to the controller so ng-click can bind to it
                 GAuth.login().then(function(user){

                 $scope.email = user.email;
                 },function(response){
                 console.log(error);});

                  GoogleAuth.grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}).then($scope.signInCallback);

                };
            });
$scope.signInCallback = function(result){

                var code = result['code'];
                var data = {
                            code : result['code'],
                            client_id: clientid,
                            client_secret:clientsecret,
                            redirect_uri:'http://localhost/myapp/oauth2callback',
                            grant_type:'authorization_code'
                            };
                $http.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',data,{headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }}).then(
               function(response){
                 // success callback
                 console.log(response);
               }, 
               function(response){
                 // failure call back
                 console.log(1);
               }
            );

        }
             }).run(['GAuth', 'GApi', 'GData', '$rootScope','$http',function(GAuth, GApi, GData,  $rootScope,$http) {
                  // Sends this header with any AJAX request
                  $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
                  // Send this header only in post requests. Specifies you are sending a JSON object
                  $http.defaults.headers.post['dataType'] = 'json'

                   $rootScope.gdata = GData;

                        var CLIENT = clientid;
                        var BASE = 'https://myGoogleAppEngine.appspot.com/_ah/api';

                        GApi.load('http://localhost','v1',BASE);
                        // GApi.load('calendar','v3'); // for google api (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/)
                        GApi.load('contacts', 'v3');
                        GApi.load('plus','v1',BASE);
                        GAuth.setClient(CLIENT);
                        GAuth.setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
}]);
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with angularjs but you can compare your code with this [Using Oauth 2.0 In Your Web Browser With AngularJS](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/03/using-oauth-2-0-in-your-web-browser-with-angularjs/) tutorial. You might have missed something about how Google’s Oauth 2.0 will get a request token when authorizing the app login, and then the request token will be exchanged for an access token.

Comment: This example shows how to integrate with Googles OAuth 2.0 for client side javascript using AngularJS. Also here a sample code [Token-based AngularJS Authentication](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer#obtaining-oauth-keys), for code implementation purposes. Hope this helps!

Comment: i found out the mistake. thanks @ Mr.Rebot